# Add session before login verification with Laravael auth

Tags: laravel, session, authentication

Laravel 5.4.

I want to set a session when an user try to login. I found I can use a login function in my LoginController.php.

My code :

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    //Set session as 'login'
    Session::put('last_auth', 'login');

}
```

It's correctly set my session but it doesn't continue the login and i get a blank page.

How can I say to my function to continue the login after set my session ?

Thanks

Comment: where is your login function code in previous code?

Comment: @HanlinWang I don't have one. It's the laravel auth who provide it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want override original laravel default login function, you can put this into `Auth\LoginController`, and remember to import `use Illuminate\Http\Request;`

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    // Here is your customized code
    Session::put('last_auth', 'login');

    $this->validateLogin($request);

    // If the class is using the ThrottlesLogins trait, we can automatically throttle
    // the login attempts for this application. We'll key this by the username and
    // the IP address of the client making these requests into this application.
    if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
        $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

        return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
    }

    if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {
        return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
    }

    // If the login attempt was unsuccessful we will increment the number of attempts
    // to login and redirect the user back to the login form. Of course, when this
    // user surpasses their maximum number of attempts they will get locked out.
    $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);

    return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
}
```

and here is register function
Import `use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;` and add:

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

    event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

    $this->guard()->login($user);

    return $this->registered($request, $user)
                    ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what i need ! Thanks. If you have the same for the register function you will help me :)

Comment: sure, I will add register function

Comment: You save my day ! Works perfectly ! I just edited it to add the import for the register function